# How to write a recursive function within a prototype function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, numbers, prototype

Lets say, I am trying a add a functionality to all "numbers" in javascript to have a function called "factorial". So, for example:

```
var num = 5
console.log( num.factorial() ) // should display 120
```

In order to achieve this, here is the following function

```
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, "factorial", {
  enumerable: false,
  value: function() {
    if(this <= 1) return 1;
    return this * factorial(this - 1);
  }
})
```

Obviously, this will return an error saying that the function "factorial" does not exist. How can one solve this problem?

Comment: maybe you should use this.factorial instead of factorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, "factorial", {
    enumerable: false,
    value: function() {
        if(this <= 1)
            return 1;
        return this * (this - 1).factorial();
    } //                   ^
});
```

As you mentioned, `factorial` is an undefined function in your question, but it *is* a function on the `Number` prototype.
So, what you want to do is call `factorial` on a number `this - 1`, in the recursion.

To be able to call the function on `this - 1`, you can just wrap it in some brackets `()`.